# Links to books in bookshelf

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, jobs

I am currently writing an experience description for my careers profile, and would like to add a link to book in my bookshelf (because I have written a comment about the book there, and I do not want to repeat it). I see no way to do this. So, can you tell me how? If not, can you add it?

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to link directly to the books in your bookshelf. While it could be a useful feature, the number of people that we think would use it is so small that it doesn't really warrant the time needed to implement it. I would either duplicate the comment (perhaps worded differently) or refer to the comment in the other section.